# How to Cancel or clean the a queue when its already started?

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

I just want to stop the queue when its already started. Is there any way to stop it? I just don't want to delete the queue but I want clean up and no message should be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the queue by simply reading and dropping all messages in the queue or use the management-plugin to empty it.